# What size wire for 180' run to shed?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, shed

My 100A main breaker panel is full. I was planning to have it ran off of the meter with 60A I have #6 thhn wire to run in conduit 180' to shed. I only need a 20 amp circuit and 15 amp circuit in shed.

Comment: It’s not really clear what you want you have a full panel and possibly want 2 circuits 160’ away? Sounds like I have a car with a motor that runs but I want  0-60 faster with Ferrari speeds. You only have a 100 amp panel without major upgrades you can not put in a 60 amp sub well you can put in a 200 amp sub but if your main is full much more info is needed. What type and size of main panel?

Comment: Can I run a line from meter to cutoff and then bury in conduit to shed?

Comment: @ArthurMillerJr. What kind of circuit breaker protection is at the meter?  A 100A breaker or no breaker?  How large is the wire going to the house?

Comment: What make and model is the panel at the meter, or is there not a panel (disconnecting means) at the meter? Also, do you know how much load the house pulls...?

Comment: CORRECTION 200A Service panel GE TLM2020 in Garage 15 ft from meter

Comment: There's your problem right there.  A 20-space panel *for a whole house*,,, no, just no, what were they thinking? *"ooh, I saved $23 on the service panel, pizza for me!"*

Comment: Can you post photos of the service panel please?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 100A service panel it's probable you only have a 100A meter and you wouldn't be able to add a 60A feeder off of that meter.

If your 100A panel is fed by a 200A meter, and 200A wire feeding it then it is possible to take another feed off the meter, but the disconnect for that additional feeder has to be grouped with the existing service disconnect, which may be beyond difficult.

Voltage drop on wire is load dependent, #6 conductors at 180' running a load of 45A would reach the maximum recommended feeder voltage drop of 3%. You would want to run #4 to keep 60A below 3% loss.

Comment: That means at 48A, voltage drop will only be 3.2%.  That does not merit a wire size bump.  If you were actually planning to draw 60A, you need to derate that by 125% and build for 75A, But again if you use 75A legal wire, you'll have barely over 3% voltage drop at 60A.

Answer (score 0):

No, because two bad/expensive things will happen.

### You'd need a main service panel at the meter.

You would need to install a main panel at the meter, to provide overcurrent protection for the #6 cable.  You can't just send it through the ground and to the shed *entirely unfused*, and if you have a 100A main breaker at the meter, 100A won't adequately protect #6 wire.

If you had #3 wire, then as long as it's past a 100A breaker, you could run 100A service to the shed with no further overcurrent complications. *Except*...

### Your cable to the house will be down-rated.

Right now, the cable to your house carries *the entire service*. As such, it gets an 83% derate (favorable). Given 100A service the wire only needs to be rated for 83 amps.

By tapping it at the meter, you violate the conditions of that favorable derate.  Now, you must bump the cable from meter to house.

### Neither is acceptable, so here's what to *really* do

Increase the size of your main panel so you have more spaces.

The number of spaces in your panel isn't magic or mandatory. That is not how electricity use is managed; that's what the main breaker is for.  There is nothing wrong with an 84-space, 100A panel.  So if your panel is full, that's a speedbump, and you can *and should* fix it.

The most obvious way is to replace your main panel. That's a lot of work, and involves live wires if you don't have an external disconnect.

The alternate plan is to install a subpanel at the main panel.  I recommed aiming for 48-ish spaces, so if your current panel is a 24-space, add another 24-space.  Only count real spaces, don't rely on those thin "double-stuff" breakers.

I would physically install the subpanel with many parallel of EMT metal conduit connecting the two panels, if possible. That will facilitate moving circuits.  The EMT conduit provides a ground path, so the subpanel won't need a wired ground.

Presuming that your subpanel has 100A rated buses, you do not need any feed or main breakers. You can simply take the subpanel off subfeed lugs, which are either built into the panel, or clip in like a breaker. I prefer #1 aluminum wire because the lugs are aluminum, so this avoids a dissimilar metal problem. But #3 copper for a 3-foot run is too cheap to care about :)  and will be slightly more flexible.

Once the subpanel is in, move 15A and 20A circuits to the subpanel.  You can use THHN/THWN-2 individual wires (go with stranded wire for easy handling) to extend the cables via the conduits into the new panel.  Al wires of the circuit go through the same conduit, don't be "clever" and run all whites through one, etc.  Wire-nut splices are allowed inside service panels.

Moving some circuits will now free up space in the main panel.  Put your shed feeder there.

If this is a roached old panel like FPE or Zinsco, or just obsolete like Pushmatic, then size and position the subpanel so it can become the new main panel someday.

### Voltage drop is not actually a concern here

Because your *actual, planned load* is considerably shy of 60A. Remember your wiring must be at least 125% of the load you actually plan to draw (e.g. on a 60A circuit, don't plan to draw more than 48A @ 240V).   This 125% bump means at 180', you'll be within sane limits on voltage drop *at the amperage you should be pulling*.

### Why on earth are you using copper wire?

Aluminum is vastly superior for feeder wires like this.  For 60A you run #4 Al.  This requires a slightly larger pipe, but for 180' of feeder, you'll save hundreds if not thousands!